# Disabled User Transport Rule

Tags: exchange-2010

I'm trying to create a Transport Rule in Exchange 2010 SP3 that would send an autoreply to the sender that the user no longer works here and to forward requests to a catch-all mailbox address.

I need it to look for a condition like "If recipient AD account status = Disabled"

Is there a way to create this condition with an EMS rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "when a recipient's properties match text patterns" or "when a recipient's properties contain specific words" condition to match messages based upon attributes of the recipient, but you can't match on UserAccountControl unfortunately.

I think you would be better off running a PowerShell script that sets an out-of-office reply for all disabled users that own a mailbox at a regular interval.